# Grunt Webpack dev server configuration

Tags: gruntjs, server, webpack

Does anyone know how to set-up the gruntfile.js and webpack.config.js files to make the webpack-dev-server working, including the hot update feature?

I mean, the simplest configuration possible to make everything up and running.

Thank you in advance,

Alex

Comment: Why are you using grunt with webpack? why not just webpack?

Comment: You're right.. Webpack alone is better. For those who need instructions in setting up Webpack, see these url: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-with-webpack-introduction

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-webpack')
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-webpack-dev-server')

    grunt.initConfig({
        'webpack': {
            dist: {
                entry: './src/entry.js',
                output: {
                    filename: 'dist/app.js'
                }
            }
        },
        'webpack-dev-server': {
           main: {
                contentBase: 'dist',
                port: 9999,
                keepAlive: true
            }
        }
    })

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['webpack', 'webpack-dev-server'])

}
```

This will spawn a dev server on localhost:9999 with document root in the /dist directory (relative to your package's root)